# Android Activity Test: How to Force Refresh

Tags: android, unit-testing

I need to test that my activity will reconfigure the view properly at different times of day. I injected a TestClock, but of course, there's no way to do that until the activity has already been created by calling `getActivity()`.

So I have a method I invoke on the `Activity`.
It updates the view properly. However, I spent hours trying to figure out why a button that should have been visible was not. Then I figured out that the view had not been refreshed, so I introduced a sleep into the test and it passed.

*Question:*
there has to be a simple way to tell the Activity to refresh the view so you can assert the results of your changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to test UI thread, you have to use `waitForIdleSync`. Refer [this](http://developer.android.com/tools/testing/activity_testing.html) for more info.

Comment: Thought I had read through that page a couple times. The testing documentation is confusing because the process has changed over time. Thanks @Yuvi!